# Taking substring of an input in MIPS failed

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm really new to assembly code and not sure what went wrong with my code... I'm only allowed to use slt, beq, bne for comparison, and lw, sw for input/output.

This program is supposed to take two integers as indices and save in $1, $2; where values should be 0 <= $1 <= $2 <= string length. String index starts from 0, if two inputs are 2,4, then substring is from index 2 to 3. At the end of substring, newline character is attached. $3=0 if indices are valid, 1 if invalid.

My code only works when $2 < $1 (an invalid case). In every other case, it would fail with an error "MIPS emulator internal error. mips.MachineException$OutOfBounds".

Below is my code, please kindly help... I have no idea what went wrong...

```
; $1 - starting index position for substring
; $2 - ending index position for substring 
; $3 - 1 when index positions invalid; 0 when index positions valid
; $4 - address of standard input
; $5 - address of standard output 
; $6 - used for comparison
; $7 - current address of character read
; $8 - New line character
; $9 - index counter
; $10 - check if substring is there
; $11 - temp

lis $4  
.word 0xffff0004
lis $5
.word 0xffff000c
lis $8
.word 0xa       ;$8=Newline character ASCII code
addi $9, $0, -1 ;initiate $9 value: $9=-1
addi $10, $0, 0 ;initiate $10=0
addi $6, $0, 1  ;$6 is 1
slt $3, $2, $1  ;if $2<$1, $3=1
beq $6, $3, end ;if $3=1, invalid index, go to end by printing newline
slt $3, $2, $0  ;if $2<0, $3=1 (0>$2>$1)
beq $6, $3, end
slt $3, $1, $0  ;if $1<0, $3=1; otherwise 0<$1<$2
beq $6, $3, end

loop:   lw $7, 0($4)    ;retrieve first element of input string
        addi $9, $9, 1  ;$9 increments index count by 1 (so start with index=0)
        slt $3, $9, $1  ;$3=1 if yet to achieve starting index
        bne $6, $3, print   ;if at starting index, go to print
        addi $4, $4, 4  ;if yet to achieve starting index, then move to next element
        beq $0, $0, loop    ;keep looping

print:  addi $10, $0, 2 ;$10=2 if need to add newline
        slt $3, $9, $2  ;$3=1 if before hitting last index
        beq $0, $3, end ;if $3=0, it means hit the last index, so go to end
        sw $7, 0($5)    ;print the desired character
        addi $4, $4, 4
        addi $5, $5, 4  ;move to next space for output
        beq $0, $0, loop

end:    addi $11, $0, 2 ;$11 is 2
        bne $11, $10, end2  ;$10=$11=2, then substring exists, add new line char
        addi $5, $5, 4
        sw $8, 0($5)  

end2:   jr $31
```

Comment: I think the problem comes from the values in $4 and $5. `lis` instructions will store the value after them in register. But these value are very high (~2^32)  and probably you do not have an underlying OS to paginate. When you try to `lw` at loop label, the simulator does not have a large enough memory and issues an error. Why not put a string in your data section and `la` it in register? BTW you should not use $1. Many asm macros use it and it can modified $1.

Comment: @AlainMerigot This is an assignment question and we didn't learn {la}...